# How to properly name an enum to use in switch case in Java Programming?

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement

On my example I'm using a `state` and `action` in `switch case` statement. I'm a little bit confuse whether to use a single `enum` which has state and action.

**Example:**

```
switch(gun.state) {
     case RELOAD: gun.state = RELOADING break;
     case RELOADING: break;
     case FIRE: gun.state = FIRING break;
     case FIRING:  break;
}
```

**Question** should I create a single `enum` or categorize it by action and state?

```
switch(gun.action) {}
switch(gun.state) {}
```

**Suggestions/Answer**
Based on the answer of Erwin Bolwidt, should I create another `enum` and categorize it by action and state?

```
public enum Action {FIRE, RELOAD};
public enum State {FIRING, RELOADING}
```

Comment: if the case is only NOUN or VERB (or both), you might be better of with a simple if/else statement block. switch is more recommended if there are more possibilities.

Comment: Java doesn't care about the English grammar in the names of your constants.

Comment: I feel that it is probably not a good idea to change the variable that you are switching on.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Why is that? It's a pretty normal use case in a state machine implementation to change the state in the cases of the switch statement.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what the actual question is.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In the above example, gun.state was `RELOAD`, then changed to `RELOADING` and then `break;`  If I were to examine the variable after the `switch` and see that its value was `RELOADING`, I may be confused as to why `RELOADING`'s process was not actioned - Maybe just my feeling?

Comment: ronscript: This is not related to the switch statement, but to the names of states. FIRE/RELOAD are *actions*, not *states*. FIRING/RELOADING are *states*, and FIRED/RELOADED would be good names for *states* too. A typical case for state machines is to change the state based on an action. So you would have an enum `Action` with elements FIRE/RELOAD and an enum `State` with elements FIRING, RELOADING, FIRED and RELOADED.